# Is it possible to use the Tridion OData Content Delivery web service with File System based storage?

Tags: content-delivery, odata

We have a requirement to use File System based storage (Content Broker) and then query the content using Tridion's OData Content Delivery web service.

I am looking for information on whether this is feasible. I remember reading somewhere in the documentation that not all metadata is stored when using the File System based Broker implementation. If that is the case, how best can OData be used in this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

When you use the local file system as the Content Data Store you are restricted in what you can do with the content on the content delivery side.

One of the things you cannot do in this scenario is query or filter published content. For Tridion 2011 this is covered in the installation manual in the sections 'Creating the Content Data Store' and 'Content Delivery system prerequisites - Functional Restrictions' (Sorry, don't have the link handy)

What this means is, in order to use Tridion's OData Web Service, you will need to use a supported database as your Content Data Store.

If there is anyway you can use a Database for your content store, on SDL's website Nuno has a great five part tutorial rife with screenshots which shows [how to configure a Tridion Content Delivery instance with the oData Web Service](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/deployer-and-odata-1.aspx).